# Why does my keyboard switch to English on various keypresses?

Tags: input-source, ukelele

When I type certain keys around the middle of the keyboard, especially around the keys `t`, `g`, `h` (regardless of modifier key), my Input Source *sometimes* jumps from my custom-made source (using Ukelele) to US English (my default).

This occurs with any hardware:  the build-in Mac keyboard or an external keyboard.

Keyboard Preferences have nothing related to this, just the default  input-source switcher (globe).

(Mac M1, OSx 12.4.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove   ⌥-Space  (under System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts-> "Select the next input source" ) and revert to the default.

(Apparently Mac reserves it for breaking-space. We have a bug here, as  as  OSX does not prevent using it or even warn you, just messes things up irregularly.)

(Answer helpfully provided by user dialabrain [on the Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254050909).)

Comment: Normally option space is used to create non breaking space characters.  The default Input Switching shortcut should be control space.  Siri's default is hold command space. Your problem is definitely odd, I've made tons of Ukelele keyboards and never seen that happen.

Comment: "create...  space characters." Thank you. I tried it now and indeed it does that, so I I am editing my text

Comment: "Switching shortcut should be control space. " Right. Ctl-Space was and is my "Select the previous input source"   shortcut. The problematic one was "Select the previous input source"  where setting it to Option-space is what caused the bug.

Comment: "Ukelele keyboards". I think now that this is not the cause. The custom keyboard was made with Ukekele. but  the fix was inside the System Preferences so I think the bug is there.

Comment: Yes, but I gather this bug also never appeared with your US keyboard active?

Comment: The bug was the same across both the built-in and the external USB (Microsoft Ergonomic) keyboard

Comment: Yes, software bugs affect all hardware keyboards.  But did you ever have the US input source switch randomly to your custom layout (instead of vice versa)?

Comment: No, the US input source never switched to the custom one (which is here https://joshuafox.com/content/HebrewYiddish.bundle.zip)